# start video background when mouse touches text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use HTML CSS aand JS and I want to to start a background video when the user hovers over a certain text. To be more precisely, I want a header with a white background and a simple text. Now when the mouse is hovered over the text, I want to start a videobackground. When the mouse than is somewhere else (not over the text) the white background should appear again. Here is a link to a homepage where you can see what I mean (try hovering over the word “digital”): https://www.agentur-loop.com/.

If there are any questions or if you don´t understand what I mean, please contact me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Epilepsy warning

Answer (score 0):

Not much to explain here:

- create your html structure
- hide video
- when mouse enters the text show video and play it
- when mouse leaves the text hide video and stop it

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video')
const text = document.querySelector('h1')

text.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  video.hidden = false
  video.play()
})

text.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  video.hidden = true
  video.pause()
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100vh;
}

header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

header video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <video hidden loop muted src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm"></video>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. And how can I extend it so that I have two different texts with two different videos? So when the user hovers over "Text 1", Video 1 should be showen and when the user hovers over "Text 2", the second video should be showen. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Ok I found a solution!